# TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'> into Vector

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataframe with multiple rows that look like this:
df.head() gives:

```
Row(features=DenseVector([1.02, 4.23, 4.534, 0.342]))
```

Now I want to compute the columnSimilarities() on my dataframe, and I do the following:

```
rdd2 = df.rdd
mat = RowMatrix(rdd2)
sims = mat.columnSimilarities()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
 File "/opt/apache-spark/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 67, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'> into Vector
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The present rdd form is:

```
Row(features=DenseVector([1.02, 4.23, 4.534, 0.342]))
```

As per the example in [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.html) it will work if we get it in form:

```
[DenseVector([1.02, 4.23, 4.534, 0.342])]
```

Construct the RowMatrix as:

```py
RowMatrix(df.rdd.map(list))
```

Here is a full example which reporduces and fixes your problem:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[([1.02, 4.23, 4.534, 0.342],)], schema=["features"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT
@udf(returnType=VectorUDT())
def arrayToVector(arrCol):
  from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
  return Vectors.dense(arrCol)
# 

df = df.withColumn("features", arrayToVector("features"))
# print(df.head())
# df.printSchema()

# mat = RowMatrix(df.rdd) # Causes TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'> into Vector
mat = RowMatrix(df.rdd.map(list))
sims = mat.columnSimilarities()
print(sims.entries.collect())

[Out]:
[MatrixEntry(2, 3, 1.0), MatrixEntry(0, 1, 1.0), MatrixEntry(1, 2, 1.0), MatrixEntry(0, 3, 1.0), MatrixEntry(1, 3, 1.0), MatrixEntry(0, 2, 1.0)]
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe an addition to the code above so that it works: make sure to add "import pyspark.sql.functions as F". And one more question: do you know why the results of the computation is always 1.0? Was trying it with several combination of numbers and cosinesimilarities gives the same result.

Comment: Updated the answer with import. I'm sorry, no idea about the computations.